# increased tablespace but dba_tablespace_usage_metrics order shows same

Tags: oracle, oracle-xe

Although I appear to have solved the problem of the tablespace being full I am perplexed that after altering the the datafile size that the tablespace size has remained the same. What is it that I don't understand?

```
SQL> alter database datafile '/usr/lib/oracle/xe/oradata/XE/system.dbf' resize 1G;

Database altered.

SQL>  select * from dba_tablespace_usage_metrics order by used_percent desc;

TABLESPACE_NAME            USED_SPACE TABLESPACE_SIZE USED_PERCENT
------------------------------ ---------- --------------- ------------
SYSTEM                  76600       76800   99.7395833
USERS                   18784      655360   2.86621094
SYSAUX                  45176     4194302   1.07708029
UNDO                      160       64000      .25
TEMP                    0     4194302        0
```

Comment: Which Oracle version? I noticed that in 10G dba_tablespace_usage_metrics quite often is showing not latest info. In 10.2.0.2 with bigger databases it was almost useless.

Comment: yeah in this case it is 10G, we have 11 in some cases, but don't know if they exhibit the same behavior.

Comment: There are problems with this view in 10g, "The DBA_TABLESPACE_USAGE_METRICS View Needs to be Rebuilt in 10g (Doc ID 738101.1)": 
"Download and apply the patch from Metalink for Bug 6629893. 
This is a generic patch which is available for: 10.1.0.5, 10.2.0.2, 10.2.0.3, 10.2.0.4. As this is a generic patch, this means the patch is essentially a script that rebuilds DBA_TABLESPACE_USAGE_METRICS prerequisite objects. 
This bug is fixed in the 10.2.0.5 patchset."